# FMS, Flex, VOD, RTMP videoDisplay to find how many seconds of video are already loaded

Tags: flex3, rtmp, flash-media-server

Good day!

I can get which part of file in bytes is loaded using videoDisplay component for RTMP protocol for VOD,  I can get the current playing position using videoDisplay.playheadTime. But I want to know how many seconds of video are already loaded (not the length of bufferTime, which remains constant). i used videoDisplay.bytesLoaded when using RTMP it returns nothing , if we uses HTTP it displays number of bytes loaded

The loaded size in bytes is not directly proportional to running time of the video, and while using rtmp im unable to get bytesLoaded too, how i can calculated the Video already loaded.

Any help is really appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need [`NetStream.bufferLength`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bufferLength) property, but i don't know how to get one from the `VideoDisplay` instance

Comment: Very thanks for your answer, bufferLength giving the reaming amount of length about to play, not how much length it gets loaded.